# For Loops Based on User Input in C

Tags: c, for-loop, recursion, comparison, user-input

I have different paths that are predefined in a 2-D array as [seed][sequence] with 'seed' being the path (0-255) and 'sequence' being the index in the path (0-49). Is there a way to neatly compare an input-defined number of paths at once when the number of paths compared may vary from run to run?

How my input is gathered:

```
#define MAX 250 

int numUsers; //the number of users
int users[MAX][2]; //each user and their respective seed
int collisions = 0; //number of collisions

static inline void compareNumUsers(){
   printf("Enter the number of users: ");
   scanf("%d", &numUsers);
   printf("\n");
   for(int i = 0; i < numUsers; i++){
      printf("Enter the seed of user%d [0-255]: ", i+1);
      scanf("%d", &users[i][1]);
   }
}
```

Best case scenario the answer is not a series of case-switch statements

I am hoping that something to the effect of this will be possible:

```
(assume 3 given inputs)
for(int j = 0; j < pathLength; j++){
    if(paths[users[0][1]][j] == paths[users[1][1]][j] || paths[users[1][1]][j] == paths[users[2][1]][j] || paths[users[2][1]][j] == paths[users[0][1]][j])
        collisions++;
}
```

I would be lying if I said I did not confuse myself when thinking how to even ask this question so if you are confused by something please ask me to verify I will not be offended.

The comparison also does not have to be in the same manner that I provided, it is just how I presently think about it.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is `users` a 2-dimensional array? You're only using the `[1]` element, what is the `[0]` element for?

Comment: Users have a number to signify themselves and a seed that determines what path they take. The number and seed do not always match up. Thinking about it, perhaps I can just compare the paths directly based on what seeds you want to look at

Comment: Isn't the user number the index of the `users` array?

Comment: Correct! I am not surprised that I overthought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested loops to compare all the pairs.

```
for (int j = 0; j < pathlength; j++) {
    for (int i = 0, broken = 0; !broken && i < numUsers - 1; i++) {
        for (int k = i + 1; k < numUsers; k++) {
            if (paths[users[i][1]][j] == paths[users[k][1]][j]) {
                collisions++;
                broken = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was on a very similar track to this, however it counts two collisions at the same index as two separate collisions when I am counting them as one collision.

Comment: You're right, because `break` only breaks out of the `k` loop, not the `i` loop. I've added another variable to fix that.

Comment: This works wonderfully. I never thought/knew of using extra parameters like that. Thank you very much!